# Devise, omniauth, ao-oauth automatic random login when switch to ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth

```
GEM ENV : 
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'omniauth', '0.3.2'
gem 'oa-oauth', '0.3.2'
gem 'devise', '1.4.7'
```

Problem :
Under ruby 1.8.7 everything works well.

When launched under ruby 1.9.3(patch 125) a random user is automatically logged in (!!!) and when we disconnect, another random user is automatically logged in ...

Is someone has had the same problem ? 
Are there some incompatibilities with 1.9.3 with one of theses gems : devise, omniauth, oa-oauth?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

This is Legacy code without functional tests nor units .... hmmm
The failure came from a method for checking "remember me" with cookies

def check_remembered
    rem_token = *cookies.signed[:remember_user_token]
    save_remember_cookie if (rem_token.nil? && user_signed_in? && current_user.remember)
    return true if rem_token.nil?  ...
    ...

BUT : With ruby 1.9 splat operator for nil return an empty array , as in ruby 1.8 it returns nil .....
Hence, code after return true was always executed and a random user was logged in ...

===> So,  .nil? have been replaced with .empty?

If it can help someone else.